# SQL Server JSON Query Filtered Return

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have the following JSON data in a single column (`varchar(max)`) related to a user:

```
[{
    "ExtensionData": {},
    "IsDefault": false,
    "MethodType": "OneWaySMS"
},
{
    "ExtensionData": {},
    "IsDefault": false,
    "MethodType": "TwoWayVoiceMobile"
},
{
    "ExtensionData": {},
    "IsDefault": false,
    "MethodType": "PhoneAppOTP"
},
{
    "ExtensionData": {},
    "IsDefault": true,
    "MethodType": "PhoneAppNotification"
}]
```

Any way to query the users record and a leverage a subquery (or something like it) to return me just the `MethodType` that is in the same block as "isDefault: true"

So the column returned would just say "PhoneAppNotification" based on the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select MethodType
from [table]
cross apply OPENJSON([column], '$')
with (IsDefault varchar(80), MethodType varchar(80))
where IsDefault = 'true'
```

Comment: You are a rockstar.... this was my final base query:

select 
 MethodType
 ,*
from adUsers
cross apply OPENJSON(AzureStrongAuthenticationMethods, '$')
 with (
  IsDefault varchar(80)
  ,MethodType varchar(80)
 )
where deleted = 0 and IsDefault = 'true'